# How do you consistently reduce fractions?

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

in math class we are given fractions like 632/6241 and are expected to know what they reduce to in under 10 seconds.

Currently, I can only guess by trial and error until I find that the common factor is 79. The problem is, much of the time I incorrectly conclude there is no common factor given the time constraint.

What is the best way to quickly reduce fractions with 4 or more digits?

Thanks.

Comment: The Euclidean algorithm is a fast way to compute the gcd of two numbers.  Even so, $10$ seconds seems a bit harsh.

Comment: 10 seconds to reduce 632/6241 is quite demanding in my opinion.

Comment: What is the point of that exercise?  Why make humans practice skills that should be left to a computer? I don't think being able to reduce fractions quickly improves understanding.

Comment: I guess you're expected to quickly know that $6241 = 79^2$ somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the Euclidean algorithm is probably the best bet unless someone memorized that $6241 = 79^2$.

One possible way of doing this specific example could be like this:
$$
x_1 = 632/6241 \\
1/x_1 = 6241/632 = (6320 - 79)/632 = 10 - 79/632 = 10  -  x_2 \\
1/x_2 = 632/79 = (790 -158)/79 = 10 - 158/79 = 10-2 = 8 \\
Therefore \\
1/x_1 = 10 - 1/8 = (80-1)/8 = 79/8 \\
x_1 = 8/79
$$

Though I doubt it is any faster than any other method in general.